# Why Solidity Inheritance Parent and Child have their respective values?

Tags: solidity

I need to split my smart contract because of the size limit, so I created Inheritance. Never did it before. But I got into trouble, I tried to go back to basics and try this code :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract parent {
  
  uint256 internal id = 9;
  
  function setValue(uint256 _value) public{
      id = _value;
  } 
  
  function getValue1() public view returns (uint256) {
    return id;
  }
}

contract child is parent {
  
   function getValue2() public view returns (uint256) {
        return id;
   }
}
```

Deployed the above contracts on Remix and my question is:

Why when I set Value on parent contract, it can't be read from child contract.

Why Parent and Child have their respective values with the same function?

Need explanation from expert.

Comment: In a comment you say both contracts were deployed, you should add that detail to the question. Deploying both is creating two unrelated contracts.

Comment: @Ismael, please copy paste my code above on Remix. You will have two contracts, (both) that's what I mean.

Comment: When developing with inheritance you only deploy the child contract.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it can be read.

If the id variable was declared `private` and not `internal` in that case, you'd not be able to access it from child smart-contract

Screenshot from remix - on the contract specified above. Maybe you just had a mistake and deployed parent - instead of child contract.

[image]

Comment: I believe the contracts were split into 2 different .sol files, just merged into one for the question redaction. In that case there is no need to deploy parent, child is enough as it will bring in the logic from parent through inheritance in one single contract.  However, it won't help you overcome any size limit, see this answer : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90803/84305

Comment: @Nikola. I deployed both. From your screenshot you just deploy the CHILD. Please deploy the parent and change with setValue from PARENT. The children can not read...??

Comment: @Yusnee I believe my previous comment answers yours ? (not sure if you get notified as I commented on the answer)

Comment: @Nikola Okay. just wondering when I deploy and verify the contract I need to deploy them all. BTW thanks for your suggestion and help.

Comment: @Yusnee no. With inheritance, you don't have to deploy Parent. Parent's logic will be included in Child contract.